# How to remove the tap head from this kind of tap?

Tags: faucet, plumbing-fixture

I couldn't find any screws at all on this tap.

How can I remove the head to replace the washer?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like to me that you need to tap the inner ring indicated with screwdriver and hammer.

[image]

Comment: Is that a locking pin screw (on top of the "t" on the word "tapping".. if so, i would recommend removing the screw before you tap the inner ring.

Comment: Hightower: Good observation!